# IPython qtconsole custom banner

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to set a custom banner for the IPython qtconsole (v3.0.0). In my profile configuration, I set `c.IPythonWidget.banner = u'Custom Banner'`, and then launch `ipython qtconsole --profile=myprof`. What I get is my custom banner pre-pended to the regular banner:

```
Custom BannerPython 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

IPython profile: myprof

In [1]:
```

How can I get ONLY my banner to print, e.g.

```
Custom Banner

IPython profile: myprof

In [1]:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but I was able to suppress the default banner by setting  `default_gui_banner=""`in the `core/usage.py` module in the IPython source. I was not able to find any way to do this without modifying the source (which is ugly), so if anyone has a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

The message you don't want is printed as part of the kernel's banner (which it gets from its shell). I was able to avoid printing it by setting the shell's `banner1` attribute to an empty string before using/connecting to the kernel elsewhere:

```
from IPython.qt.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager
kernel_manager = QtInProcessKernelManager()
kernel_manager.start_kernel()
kernel_manager.kernel.shell.banner1 = ""
```

I've only worked with/tested this with the IPython Qt stuff, so this might not work for other kernels.